# Parameterized UPDATE in SQLite and C# throwing an exception

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have been staring at this code too long.  This block keeps throwing an exception which says :

```
{System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQL logic error or missing database
         near ",": syntax error
```

That sounds like it could be the forming of my SQL, but I don't see it.

I know the process of creating and filling the parameters is correct.  It works in other places of the same application.  The SQL looks good when I check it as a string, but I cannot check it just before it goes to the SQLite engine.

Research has confirmed my process, but I am missing something or a typo is just hiding from me. Can you please take a look and see if the error stands out to you? Is there a better way to go about this?

**Code**

```
public static int updatePartner( Partner updatedPartner, Partner oldPartner)
{
    int result = 0;
    SQLiteConnection connection = GroomwatchDB.GetConnection();

    string sqlStatement = "UPDATE partners SET [last_name] = @lastName, [first_name] = @firstName, " 
        + "[pay_rate] = @payRate, [active] = @uactive "
        + "WHERE [partner_code] = @oldPartnerCode, [last_name] = @oldLastName, [first_name] = @oldFirstName "
        + "[pay_rate] = @oldPayRate, [active] = @oldActive";

    MessageBox.Show(sqlStatement);

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@lastName"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@firstName"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@payRate"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@uactive"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@oldPartnerCode"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@oldLastName"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@oldFirstName"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@oldPayRate"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@oldActive"));
    command.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = updatedPartner.Last_name;
    command.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = updatedPartner.First_name;
    command.Parameters["@payRate"].Value = updatedPartner.Pay_rate;
    command.Parameters["@uactive"].Value = updatedPartner.Active;
    command.Parameters["@oldPartnerCode"].Value = oldPartner.Code;
    command.Parameters["@oldLastName"].Value = oldPartner.Last_name;
    command.Parameters["@oldFirstName"].Value = oldPartner.First_name;
    command.Parameters["@oldPayRate"].Value = oldPartner.Pay_rate;
    command.Parameters["@oldActive"].Value = oldPartner.Active;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();              
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I believe you're missing AND's in the Where Statement

so it would be

```
"WHERE [partner_code] = @oldPartnerCode AND [last_name] = @oldLastName AND [first_name] = @oldFirstName "
    + " AND [pay_rate] = @oldPayRate AND [active] = @oldActive";
```

Comment: Good catch @eddie_31003, but I still get the same exception thrown after I correct that.  :(  It must be earlier in the statement. Clearly I have been staring too long.

Comment: I updated my response @KeithKolbo. I believe you're missing the AND Operator in your WHERE Clause

Comment: Of course that was the problem with the SQL.  I think I was on planet stupid tonight.

Comment: Now with that fixed, the code still bombs.  I get: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): database is locked
database is locked  I can still read and write to the database file with the SQLite command-line tools, so something else is going on.  I guess this is a new question.  What cold cause a databased locked for a c# application but still have it open for other programs? @eddie_31003

Comment: I found where in my application, or after what action the database is being left locked. The lock is happening in the application for sure.  I will start another question with the code that appears to be leaving it lock.